# How to set back the right default program for .vmoptions files?

Tags: default-programs

By accident, I set notepad as default program to open .vmoptions files. And now my programs that have these files won't open. But before they had opened, so I guess I don't need to download any soft. How to change it back? What is the right default program?

Comment: What OS are you using? On Windows 10 you should be able to select "Choose a default app for each type of file" (simply search for it), find the .vmoptions file extension and change the association back to the original program

Comment: I'm using Windows 8. The problem is I cannot find the original program